# AndroidX Jetifier Mockito java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for com/samsung/android/sdk/accessory/SAAgentV2.class

Tags: java, android, mockito, samsung-mobile-sdk, android-jetifier

I am migrating my app to use [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). I have enabled Jetifier in my gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I use mockito in some tests. After migration a few tests fail where mockito is not able to mock classes which use [Samsung accessory sdks](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory#) version 2.6.1 .

Part of exception log is as under

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA-256 digest error for
>   com/samsung/android/sdk/accessory/SAAgentV2.class     at
>   sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:218)
>     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:241)     at
>   java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(JarVerifier.java:482)
>     at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:462)

I believe this happens due to a signed jar being edited by jetifier. 
What can be done to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't find any answer for last 3 days, so I just removed META-INF from the samsung accessory jar.

```
jar xvf accessory-2.6.1..jar

rm -rf META-INF

jar cvf accessory-2.6.1-updated..jar *
```

Now will need to check if the accessory apis are working or not.

Comment: Same thing happening to me... Will also test this. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio preferences, you can turn off Instant Run. This seemed to fix the issue for our app's build without any other changes. It's in Preferences > Build, Execution, Environment > Instant Run.

Comment: Not related to Android Studio.

Comment: Could you have this option activated in another way then? My team faced the same issue, though we're all using Android Studio for our local builds. If you're doing something different, perhaps ensure that Instant Run is not activated in another way.